# Yii framework : use Url Manager for 'rename' a controller?

Tags: yii

What should I do if I want to make a 'urlName' of a controller ?

In the URL :
http://examplate.com/theBook/someAction

And I want to route to a controller named 'Book' instead of 'TheBook',
Can Url Manager do the task ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ragingprodigy is right, but you could also use the controllerMap options

> mapping from controller ID to controller configurations. Each name-value pair specifies the configuration for a single controller. A controller configuration can be either a string or an array. If the former, the string should be the class name or class path alias of the controller. If the latter, the array must contain a 'class' element which specifies the controller's class name or class path alias. The rest name-value pairs in the array are used to initialize the corresponding controller properties.

For example in your config file if you define

```
'controllerMap'=>array(
    'Book'=>array(
       'class'=>'path.to.TheBook',
    ),
)
```

Then  `http://examplate.com/Book/someAction` will call the method `actionSomeAction` in `TheBook` controller

**Edit**

Then in the controler when you are using `render` or `renderPartial` indicate also the folder the view is in:

```
$this->render("//thebook/yourView");
```

Comment: 'path.to.TheBook' what should be in it ? My question is : when vist "http://examplate.com/theBook/someAction" then make yii using "BookController/someAction". the controller is just place at "/protected/controllers" folder.

Comment: Damn ! it need to place at outside the "components" array ! I never understand the Yii Doc without a example. Thanks any way.
I got the answers at http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/9449-problem-with-controllermap/page__p__46746__hl__controller+map#entry46746

Comment: I can go to the controller named 'BookController.php' now, But I still need to rename the view. what should i do ?

Comment: What you mean rename the view?

Comment: after I used controllerMap, there is a message "cannot find the requested view" if I use $this->render(). Then I found i will need rename the the view folder to make it work.

Comment: See my edit, you have to also tell in what folder the view is

Comment: if the view folder's location is "/protected/views/book", what is the value in render() ?

Comment: try $this->render('//book/yourview'); if it doesn't work try $this->render('/book/yourview');

Answer (score 0):

yes this is possible. Just specify your url routes like this:

```
return array(
    'urlManager' => array(
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'rules' => array(
            'Book/<action:\w+>' => 'theBook/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),

);
```

Comment: I have try them before the ask.
I have try both 'Book/<action:\w+>' => 'theBook/<action>', & 'theBook/<action:\w+>' => 'Book/<action>',  still not working. err msg : Error 404

Unable to resolve the request "theBook".

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-controllers#controller-ids it looks like yii uses a `-` to separate CamelCase words in the controller name.

So the correct way to do the routing fo `book/<action:\w+>` to the controller `TheBookController` would be:

```
return array(
    'urlManager' => array(
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'rules' => array(
            'book/<action:\w+>' => 'the-book/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),

);
```

The same rule apples for CamelCase action names
, see [Yii2 routing when using CamelCase action names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25697106/yii2-routing-when-using-camelcase-action-names)