# Yii2 actionname with Uppercase do not work

Tags: yii2, action, uppercase, camelcasing

i am using windows with yii2 advanced template. if i create an action like: actionShowInvoiced i am getting Error: Not Found #404 (Page not Found.

If i name the Action actionShowinvoiced it is working.

of course i call the function like /customer/showinvoiced or /customer/showInvoiced

i found this: [Yii2 routing when using CamelCase action names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25697106/yii2-routing-when-using-camelcase-action-names)

but i am not sure where i have to make this changes....
please help!

Comment: Can you show the URL which gives #404?

Comment: call action like `/customer/show-invoiced`.

Answer (score 3):

If your action is like "action**ShowInvoiced**" in Customer Controller, you should call it as '/customer/**show-invoiced**'.

If your action is like "action**Showinvoiced**" in Customer Controller, you should call it as '/customer/**showinvoiced**'.